# My getlines are showing an error as well as my get functions when I put in a variable in the parentheses c++

Tags: c++, setter, getline

I have a banking project and I am trying to set up the bank name, address, and working hours. My `getline`s are showing an error as well as my `get` functions.

```
Input exact error messages here please.
'getline': no matching overloaded function found   
no suitable user-defined conversion from "Bank" to "std::string" exists
```

Here's the class for bank:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Bank {
public:
    void setBankName(string bn) { bn = bankname; }
    string getBankName() { return bankname; }
    void setBankAdd(string ba) { ba = bankadd; }
    string getBankAdd() { return bankadd; }
    void setWorkingHours(string bwh) { bwh = bankworkinghours; };
    string getWorkingHours() { return bankworkinghours; }

private: 
    string bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;
};

//and then this is in my main function
int main() {
    Bank bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;
    char userChoice; // numbers 1-9

    int number=0;
    system ("color 5f");
    cout << "Name of bank: ";
    getline(cin, bankname); **//all the get lines also show error**
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bank address: ";
    getline(cin, bankadd);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bank working hours: ";
    getline(cin, bankworkinghours);
    cout << endl;
    bankname.setBankName(bankname); //the things in the parentheses show error
    bankadd.setBankAdd(bankadd);
    bankworkinghours.setWorkingHours(bankworkinghours);
```

Comment: Please provide the exact verbatim error messages.

Comment: The problem with `getline(cin, bankname);` is that `bankname` is a `Bank` not a `std::string`. This line seems to be a source of several bugs: `Bank bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;`

Comment: 'getline': no matching overloaded function found

Comment: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Bank" to "std::string" exists

Comment: Also, how would I connect my cins to my class function without using Bank as that causes error.

Comment: So I fixed it to make them strings but now this is having issues:

Comment: bankname.setBankName(bankname); //errorwhere it says setBankName
bankadd.setBankAdd(bankadd); //error where it says setBankAdd
bankworkinghours.setWorkingHours(bankworkinghours); //error where it says setWorkingHours                                                                                                            the exact message for all three is "  'setBankAdd/setBankWorkingHours/setBankName': is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' "

Comment: @MahNoor put code in the question unless it's a small line. It's hard to read in comments.

Comment: You should have `Bank bank;` not `Bank bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;` I assume you want to input data for a single bank. You also need to declare a `std::string` in `int main()`  perhaps `std::string mystring;` and use that with your `getline(cin,mystring);` then use your set function in your `Bank` class `bank.setBankName(mystring);`

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. 2nd parameter of getline function is std:string so define bankname as std:string and then set the name of bank object by setBankName.

Answer (score 0):

1- You did not created bank Object in the main to set class attributes.
You need an Object with reference to that object you will set the parameters of the class bank.

2- bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours are string and you made them Bank

Here is updated code and working fine in VS 2019 without any error. Just a few changes in the first 2 and last three lines of main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Bank {
public:
    void setBankName(string bn) { bn = bankname; }
    string getBankName() { return bankname; }
    void setBankAdd(string ba) { ba = bankadd; }
    string getBankAdd() { return bankadd; }
    void setWorkingHours(string bwh) { bwh = bankworkinghours; };
    string getWorkingHours() { return bankworkinghours; }

private:
    string bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;
};

//and then this is in my main function
int main() {

    Bank bankObj;
    string bankname, bankadd, bankworkinghours;

    char userChoice; // numbers 1-9

    int number = 0;
    system("color 5f");
    cout << "Name of bank: ";
    getline(cin, bankname); 
        cout << endl;
    cout << "Bank address: ";
    getline(cin, bankadd);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bank working hours: ";
    getline(cin, bankworkinghours);
    cout << endl;

    bankObj.setBankName(bankname);
    bankObj.setBankAdd(bankadd);
    bankObj.setWorkingHours(bankworkinghours);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

void setBankName(string bn) { bn = bankname; } is the wrong way around. try bankname = bn.

Comment: I did not downvote however I suspect one reason for downvoting is there are multiple bugs and you only solved 1 of them. Although with that said some people will downvote when you answer a poor quality question.

Comment: I did not downvote either, but when I tried this "fix" it threw out 24 errors rather than the 6 I was having